# How to swap pairs of bits of unsigned int in C

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

This is the code I have so far? But its not working..

```
uint64_t bit_swap(uint64_t value) {
    return ((value & 0xAAAAAAAA) >> 1) |
            ((value & 0x55555555) << 1);   
}
```

bit_swap(0x1111111111111111) should return 0x2222222222222222 but is returning 0x0000000022222222 instead

Comment: What is the code supposed to do exactly? "swap bits" is hardly very precise.

Comment: its supposed to return value with pairs of bits swapped. sorry will edit the question now

Comment: Can you please give some examples of input, expected result and actual result?

Comment: bit_swap(0x1111111111111111) should return 0x2222222222222222
but is returning 0x0000000022222222,

Comment: If you do `& 0xAAAAAAAA` it's obvious that the top 32 bits will always be 0 since they are always anded with 0. Try it with  `& 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
value & 0xAAAAAAAA
```

That is equivalent to : `value & 0x00000000AAAAAAAA`

And since we know that anything anded with 0 will give 0 hence the top 32 bits will always be 0. Change to:

```
return ((value & 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA) >> 1) |
        ((value & 0x5555555555555555) << 1);
```